# How to clear Firebase data without losing them? Like transferring them somewhere else. #AskFirebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to clear data in firebase. However, I want to hold the information. Here is my firebase data structure:

[image: Data Structure]

I want to clear values under solved child or tranffering them into another new child. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no transfer of data.

You would read in the Solved node in code, then write the solved node as a child of another node in code.

Then set the solved node to nil (null) which will remove (clear) all of the child data.

You could also use .removeValue as well.

It's not posted in your question but in swift, it could also be

```
let solvedRef = rootRef.child("Users/sxjl.../Caps/Level 1/Solved")      
solvedRef.setValue("")
```